# How to pass Session Attributes to Lex Bot from Botium Client?

Tags: testing, chatbot, amazon-lex

I need to pass "Session Attributes" from botium to Lex Bot - how can i do it ? Am using container mode as "lex", when i run the convos i get "BadRequestException: Invalid Bot Configuration: No usable messages given the current slot and sessionAttribute set."
Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You cant pass Session Attribute yet. I create an issue for that. We will implement it in few weeks.

2) I did not see this BadRequestException yet, but it looks like it is coming because lex. Or is the intent working in general? See this please: [error: No usable messages given the current slot and sessionAttribute set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863158/error-no-usable-messages-given-the-current-slot-and-sessionattribute-set)

Comment: When can i expect this enhancement ?

Comment: It is published now (botium-connector-lex 0.0.2)